# How to CSS target a row based upon its content, not attributes

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I'm using software that isn't very specific in its naming/targeting. I'm trying to target a row that contains the label Interests. I cannot add new classes.

This works too well:

```
.resultsList .row:nth-child(2) {color:red;}
```

The red text then appears anywhere on the website that uses .resultsList. I need to specifically target result-labels that *only* have Interests within it like so:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="result-label col-tn-3">Interests</div>
<div class="result-value col-tn-9">Sailing</div>
</div>
```

Any help? I've tried targeting using the whole class on Interests but I also turned other rows red that weren't Interests. I may be able to use plain Javascript on this but CSS would be better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jquery! (.result-label is your target element/s class)

```
$(".resultsList .result-label").css("color", "red");
```

In Vanilla JS!

```
document.querySelector(".resultsList .result-label").style.color = "red";
```

In CSS!

```
.resultsList .result-label {color:red }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! This would target ALL labels to be red but I want only the labels that say "Interests." I'm unable to add any classes to this software so I have to try targeting things in other ways. Do you have any other ideas that I may try? 

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can try this using JS => 
var xpath = "//div[text()='Interests']";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

matchingElement.style.color = "red";

Comment: Thank you, @Mateen! Your answer worked perfectly. If you want to leave a new standalone comment, I'll mark it as the right answer. In my case, the full code was: 

```<script type="text/javascript">

var xpath = "//div[text()='Interests']"; var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; matchingElement.style.color = "purple";

</script>```

Comment: Yes, please mark it as the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I didn't properly understand the case, but you want to only have red text those labels that have interests, right?
If it's the case, why you can't simply create a new class (for example, `interest-label`) and enter `color: red` in that? then for the tags you want, you simply add `class="interest-label"`.

```
.resultsList .row:nth-child(2) {color:red;}
```

The css you wrote will apply color red to all elements of .resultsList and also to the second child of the row inside an element with class resultsList.

Would you please share more of your code and/or specify lil bit more what do you want to end with?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't have the ability to apply new classes with this product. I can only apply CSS (and maybe JavaScript) if I can figure out how to target the row that has the Interests label.