# Use XPath to select all values on a page and replace content

Tags: javascript, css, xpath

I want to replace every instance of the word "Specialization" with "Profession." This is the XPath code I have so far:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

var xpath = "//div[text()='Specialization']"; 
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
matchingElement.style.color = "red";

</script>
```

My thanks to @Mateen for their help with my original question for [writing the above line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274203/how-to-css-target-a-row-based-upon-its-content-not-attributes/71274263?noredirect=1#comment126007320_71274263) for me in the first place.

Comment: Note that the "at username" functionality only notifies users when used in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need an XPath solution, but if you want to stick with the standard DOM API, here's a simple solution.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(function(d){
  if(d.textContent.includes("Foo")){
    d.textContent = d.textContent.replace("Foo","FooBar");
    d.classList.add("match");
  }
});
```

```css
.match { color:#f00; }
```

```html
<div>Foo is cool</div>
<div>Bar is not</div>
<div>Foo is cool</div>
<div>Bar is not</div>
<div>Foo is cool</div>
<div>Bar is not</div>
<div>Foo is cool</div>
<div>Bar is not</div>
<div>Foo is cool</div>
<div>Bar is not</div>
<div>Foo is cool</div>
<div>Bar is not</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had the very interesting experience of that breaking my site. I had wrapped it in Javascript tags like so: 
```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(function(d){
  if(d.textContent.includes("Foo")){
    d.textContent = d.textContent.replace("Foo","FooBar");
    d.classList.add("match");
  }
});
</script>
```
<br />

I did that because the software I'm using said that I needed to have tags around it.

Comment: @user3753138 What does "breaking my site" mean? What error did you get? What line of the code was where the error occurred? As you can see, the code works, so whatever problem you are having is most likely related to something else. Also (FYI) `type="text/javascript"` is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how to explain it other than I put it in and suddenly I had a big block of text in the center of my screen of my website's text content without any further images or styling. Fortunately, it seems to be contained to just that place in the system where I could add the JS (but now I can't delete it out). 

I'll talk to the developer of the software tomorrow to see if they have any leads.